# Create a list of users in an Azure group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there away I can download a list of all the users in an Azure group to an excel file? We have large Azure groups and want an easier way to send a list to a group of users for review. It would be even better if I could automate this procedure maybe even email it to the users once a week.

I hope you can help!
Colin

Comment: Hi, @C Edw. Are there any updates? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly [bulk download the members of a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-bulk-download-members#to-bulk-download-group-membership) in your organization to a CSV file using Azure AD Portal. It seems the easiest way.

The other methods need to loop all users in the group. The following is an example with Powershell.

```
$group_ObjectId = ""
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group_ObjectId -All $true 
ForEach ($member in $members){ 
    Write-output $group.DisplayName "," $member.ObjectId "," $member.ObjectType $member.UserType "," $member.UserPrincipalName >> C:\scripts\output.csv
}
```

And create weekly scheduled task with [`Scheduled Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=win10-ps). For more details, see [here](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-scheduled-task/#Creating_a_New_Scheduled_Task).

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument '-File C:\scripts\getUserList.ps1' 
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek Saturday -At 3am

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Task Name Here"
```